# How to geocode location using twittersearch for leaflet map of tweets

Tags: python, leaflet, twitter

I'm using twittersearch to iterate over user input topics and location of interest that will then be visualized in a leaflet map. So using 'place' I can get a map, no problem. I'm trying to increase my odds of getting points by using 'location' in another for loop. Do I need to geocode the location data, if so what am I missing?

Geocode piece..

```
from geopy import geocoders

def geo(location):
    g = geocoders.Nominatim()
    loc = g.geocode(location)
    return loc.latitude, loc.longitude
```

original 'place' piece that produces results..

```
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
    tweetText = ( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) ).encode("ascii", "ignore")
    print tweetText
    if tweet['place'] is not None:
        (lat, lng) = geo(tweet['place']['full_name'])
        tw = tweet['text']
        user= tweet['user']['screen_name']
        #map has markers placed at the location of the tweet, the pop up text is the contenet of the the tweet and the poster/user
        #this is in the form of username said tweet content
        folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup= user + " said " + tw,icon=folium.Icon(color='red',icon='info-sign')).add_to(mapLeafletPython)
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % (user, tw) + 'And they said it from (' + str(lat) +', ' +str(lng)+')').encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

this is the location piece that produces this error...AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
which occurs on the (lat1, lng1) line.

```
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
    tweetText = ( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) ).encode("ascii", "ignore")
    if tweet['user'] is not None:
        (lat1, lng1) = geo(tweet['user']['location'])
        tw = tweet['text']
        user= tweet['user']['screen_name']
        #map has markers placed at the location of the tweet, the pop up text is the contenet of the the tweet and the poster/user
        #this is in the form of username said tweet content
        folium.Marker([lat1, lng1], popup= user + " said " + tw,icon=folium.Icon(color='blue',icon='info-sign')).add_to(mapLeafletPython)
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % (user, tw) + 'And they said it from (' + str(lat) +', ' +str(lng)+')').encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

"tweetSearchUser" is the input from user as well as "where"

last piece that I think you need for testing besides variable ts which is the token..

```
tso = TwitterSearchOrder() # create a TwitterSearchOrder object
tso.set_keywords([tweetSearchUser]) # let's define all words we would like to have a look for
#tso.set_count(200) #limit return records to a number
tso.set_include_entities(False) # and don't give us all those entity information
```

Using this as a reference for twitter api and json format

http://socialmedia-class.org/twittertutorial.html

https://github.com/MichaelMartinez/blog/blob/master/content/iPython-Notebooks/Python-Twitter-Tools.md

I'm baffled here...

Updated with error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/) geocoder will return a None object if a location can't be geocoded. For example:

```
>>> g = geocoders.Nominatim()
>>> loc = g.geocode("This place doesn't exist")
>>> type(loc)
NoneType
```

You'll need to take a look at the locations coming in from the user location, and probably through a `try...except` block around getting those results.

Comment: That thought had occurred to me but I've tried so many different things...kind of got lost in the fray...thanks a lot.

Comment: Is location going to be iterable and provide coordinates?

Comment: @Staley Not 100% sure, but I don't think so - certainly not in all cases. I believe it's the bit of location text that appears under the profile name on twitter which can be set to anything - the example in the twittersearch API is `'location': u"SwiekeCity\u2022PinkBabyRoom's",`.

Comment: So really I need to find another route if there is one...thanks again